# MySQL optimized query for not in

Tags: mysql

I have an excel with VBA program which connects to MySQL database to retrieve some information. Initially, when the program loads I have the below query.

```
SELECT A.id,A.first_name,A.last_name FROM Table1 A WHERE A.ID NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT  
SUBJECT FROM Table2)
```

TABLE 1 has data like below.

- 1 Christian   Bale
- 2 Christopher Nolan
- etc

TABLE 2 has data like below.

- 1 acted_in Batman
- 2 directed Batman
- etc

My query given above works perfectly fine as long as the total rows are less in table 2. However, currently my data has 26000 rows in table 1 and 102000 rows in table 2. So, when I run the above query in my program, it takes around half an hour to execute the query and sometimes it doesn't execute properly. I tried the below query too but it also takes long time.

```
SELECT  A.id, A.first_name, A.last_name FROM Table1 a 
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT  1
    FROM    Table2 al
    WHERE   a.id = al.subject
)
```

Is there an efficient way to rephrase the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an outer join

```
SELECT A.*
FROM Table1 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT subject
            FROM Table2) b ON a.id = b.subject
WHERE b.subject IS NULL
```

Comment: Is this dependent on MySQL version? I get an SQL syntax error.

Comment: Fixed it, it should be LEFT OUTER JOIN, not OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other offered answer, however the query may perform better with a direct link to the table rather than to an inline view on a SELECT DISTINCT:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.subject
WHERE t2.subject IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Table1 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT subject
                  FROM Table2 b
                  WHERE a.id = b.subject)
```