# Excel VBA program stopped executing MySQL query

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I have a problem with my excel VBA application. I use my excel VBA to connect to MySQL to fetch some values from the database. The query is a "**Left outer join**" which joins the non existing data of table 1 with table 2. Table 1 has 26000 rows and Table 2 has 320000 rows. More details of my query can be found in the below link.

[MySQL optimized query for not in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462616/mysql-optimized-query-for-not-in)

The VBA code was working perfectly fine till today morning. I was getting an "**There was a problem sending the command to the program**" warning in the morning. However, I just ignored the warning and executed the program. It worked. After stopping the program ,I decided to fix the above error. I just did the "Fix it" solution for the error from Microsoft site and my program stopped executing the above query. I feel clueless as to what would have happened.

- I re-installed the excel twice (Microsoft professional plus 2010), but no use.
- I ran the query in MySQL server to check if there is something wrong with the query. It works perfectly fine and takes around 4 minutes to execute.
- I tried changing the compatibility mode of excel (C:/program Files(x 86)/Microsoft Office/Excel). It did not help.
- I ran my program for around half an hour but strangely my program is not executing the query.
- I believe I might have changed my settings unknowingly. But even after reinstallation of office, why I am not able to execute the query?

**EDIT:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Start
End Sub

Function Start()
Dim f1, f2, f3, Increment
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rsPass As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql As String
Dim strBatchName, obj, res

Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
oConn.Open "ramesh"
sql = "My Left outer join query goes here"
Set obj = oConn.Execute(sql)
Do Until obj.EOF
Sleep 1000
f1 = obj.Fields(0).Value
f2 = obj.Fields(1).Value
f3 = obj.Fields(2).Value
Increment = GetMaximumID
Search f1:=f1, f2:=f2, f3:=f3, 
Increment:=Increment
obj.MoveNext
Loop
oConn.Close
End Function

Function GetMaximumID() As Integer

Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rsPass As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql As String
Dim Increment, obj
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
oConn.Open "ramesh"
sql = "SELECT max(id) FROM AutoIncrementor"
Set obj = oConn.Execute(sql)
Increment = obj.Fields(0).Value
oConn.Close
GetMaximumID = Increment
End Function

Function Search goes here
```

Comment: It's pretty much impossible for us to guess what the problem might be, particularly with no code to view...

Comment: I have added some code. Hope it might be enough. If you need more, I can post it in a private chat window.

Comment: So, what line does it error on?

Comment: It doesn't throw an error on any line. The query takes unusually longer time to execute. Normally, it gets executed in around 5 minutes and goes to the search function. However, I ran my code for half an hour and it doesn't show up anything. I tried with relatively simpler queries and they seemed to work fine.

Comment: Have you tried setting break points to see where the execution reaches?

Comment: It reaches till the query part.                                       sql = "My Left outer join query goes here"                                                                 After that, it stays indefinitely on that line. I have to close the excel from task manager.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32986/discussion-between-ramesh-and-tim-williams)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, seems compatibility issues was creating the problem. I was using Microsoft professional plus 2010. I re-installed the office and followed most of the steps mentioned in the below link.
http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/StartupProblems.asp.

As a final resolution, I did the following steps.

- Opened C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14.
- Right click on Excel.exe and select Properties
- Select compatibility and unchecked the option "Run this program in compatibility mode for".