# MySQL query for not exists in another table

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have two MySQL Tables...

```
1. master_fee
2. fees_receiving_ledger
```

I do not want to show the `FeeId` containing `FeeFrequencyId : 4` from `master_fee` table if they are present in `fees_receiving_ledger` table.

[image: table description]

Like above I do not want to show the **Admission Fee** `(FeeId:1)` containing `FrequencyId : 4` as it is present in **fees_receiving_ledger**.

I have tried like below...

```
Select
  master_fee.*
From
  master_fee
Where Not Exists(Select
    fees_receiving_ledger.FeeId
From
    fees_receiving_ledger
Where
    fees_receiving_ledger.FrequencyId = '4')
```

My query giving me blank result.

I tried [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462616/mysql-optimized-query-for-not-in) but failed.

What should be the query ?

I am using `VB.NET` with `MySQL` database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot the join condition in your subselect.

```
select m.* from master_fee m 
where not exists (
    select 1 from 
        fees_receiving_ledger f 
        where f.frequencyID = 4 
        and m.feeid=f.feeid)
```

You could also do:

```
select m.* from master_fee m left join fees_receiving_ledger f 
on f.feeid = m.feeID
where f.frequencyID <> 4;
```

Comment: Thanks LSA for your fast answer. Could you please tell me what is **1** in `(select 1 from... ` ?

Comment: It is just a placeholder replace it with what ever you want like '42' or 'test' or 'x'. You could put `f.FeeId` here, but thats less efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.